# Bitcoin pool with GETWORK support

Tags: mining-pools, getwork

I study bitcoin and found a simple open source miner on githab. It runs on the CPU, and uses the outdated GetWork protocol, but it's enough to study. Is there now a bitcoin pool that still supports the GetWork?

Answer (score 2):

GetWork requires you to make a new request every 2**32 nonces, modern miners would be making 50,000+ requests a second. No pools have supported this since 2011.