# How to solo mine bitcoin if the blockchain is on an external hard drive?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, solo-mining, minerd

I am trying to solo mine bitcoin but the blockchain has been downloaded to an external hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the full blockchain in order to solo mine. A pruned node works just fine and requires only a few gigabytes of storage.

If you join what's called a "solo mining pool", you don't need to run a node at all, provided that you're okay with a small level of trust towards the mining pool and with a small percentage fee taken from your reward in the highly unlikely event that you actually manage to find a block.

Comment: Is there a solo mining pool with Getwork protocol? My ASICs can't connect with stratum..

Comment: According to [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/68641/121614), no mining pools have supported getwork since 2011.